# An active access token must be used to query information about the current user & OAuthException [code] => 2500

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

When user access token , I am *getting error* like . 
Please help me immediately. How can I solve this,tell me

> stdClass Object ( [error] => stdClass Object ( [message] => An active
>   access token must be used to query information about the current user.
>   [type] => OAuthException [code] => 2500 ) )

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
require("facebook.php");

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '1501716620042981',
  'app_secret' => '510d15193610ca682b7f79c156992bb5',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
  ]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();


try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
  // Logged in!
 echo $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

  // Now you can redirect to another page and use the
  // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} 



     $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/me/?fields=albums.fields(id,name,cover_photo,photos.fields(name,picture,source)),videos.type(uploaded)&'.$_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'fb');
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    # Return response instead of printing.
    $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);


    print_r(json_decode($query));
```

Comment: Why are you using the PHP SDK only “half the way”? Instead of using cURL to make that request, use the class the SDK provides for that. “Splitting” it this way, using the SDk for login, and then abandoning it for something completely different, seems to make no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 8):

You're not providing the access token in the right way. It should be presented as the value of the `access_token` URL query parameter as in:

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/me/?fields=albums.fields(id,name,cover_photo,photos.fields(name,picture,source)),videos.type(uploaded)&access_token='.$_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
```

for clarity, without the specific fields:

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
```

Comment: i am using same url as you specified but its still not working same error

Comment: Sweet Jebus, I was searching for a right answer long time... last used the fbook login on graph v2.2... lot changed... Thanks!